# provider view model with collection of objects

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a state model that has collection of objects that have a collection of objects inside as well (think collection of todo lists):

```
class StateModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    List<TodoList> todoLists;
}
```

simplified TodoList class looks like this:

```
class TodoList {
    int id;
    List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    int id;
    String name;
    bool status; // true is done, false is not done
}
```

Now one of my Views is ListView of my todo lists (where I display only name) and that's east. But I want to have a todo list detail view (where data of single todo list is displayed) where I want to mark todo items as done (i.e. set their status to true). How should I do it? I could have method in StateModel which would find a TodoList object by id, then mark items as done. This could look something like this:

```
class StateModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    // (...)
    void markItemAsDone(listId, itemId) {
        // find todo list in StateModel
        // find item in given list
        // mark it as done
        // notifyListeners()
    }
}
```

But this seems wrong. What I would like to have is a way to get TodoList object view model and use its methods, not StateModel methods. How should I approach this? Can I have another view model (TodoListState), and have a collection of TodoListState objects in StateModel? Is this a use case for ProxyProvider?

I hope my question is clear, let me know if this needs more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My way is when you the pop back from the detail view, you also transfer a value:
I **await** for the value from the pop back then you do something with the value. Here is my code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WordModel provider = Provider.of<WordModel>(context);
    return Consumer<WordModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) => InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          dynamic status = await Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder<ListFavouriteWord>(
               pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                  Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
            return ListFavouriteWord(value);
          }));
          //do something with markedValue
          //provider.update(status)

        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 16.0),
          child: Badge(
            child: Icon(Icons.face),
            badgeContent: Text(
              "${value.counter}",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .button
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have found another way to do it. You just need: 
`ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` to use your provider in your previous route

My code:

```
onTap: () async {
          dynamic markedValue = await Navigator.of(context).push(
              PageRouteBuilder<ListFavouriteWord>(
         pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
            return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: value,
              child: ListFavouriteWord(),
            );
          }));

        }
```